# How to fix ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, relative-import

I was working on a "hoop detection" program for FRC, and I wanted to organize the structure. I created the `__init__.py`s, rearranged the imports and updated the paths. Then I ran my code which is in `misc/calibration/`. After all, I got the error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I tried some stuff but none of them worked.

Here is my project tree:

```
├── cascade.xml
├── images
│   ├── ref-pic.jpeg
│   └── ref-pic-post.jpeg
├── LICENSE
├── misc
│   ├── bash
│   │   ├── install_os_dependencies.sh
│   │   ├── pip_install.sh
│   │   └── set_camera.sh
│   ├── calibration
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── pixel-calculator.py
│   │   └── shoot-a-photo.py (This is the one I'm trying to run.)
│   ├── functions
│   │   ├── fix_camera.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── set_camera.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── viewer.py
├── requirements.txt
├── settings.ini
├── settings.ini.template
└── vision.py

5 directories, 19 files
```

And here is my import statement:

```
from ..functions import set_camera
```

And the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/egeakman/repos/vision-2021/misc/calibration/shoot-a-photo.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..functions import set_camera
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This is the project repository if it makes any good: https://github.com/Scorpions-Robotics/vision-2021

Should I import it differently or is there another way?
Thanks in advance, have a good day.

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D With `python shoot-a-photo.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I import it differently or is there another way?

No, the import is alright. It instructs python to go to the *parent package* (of the package the file you are running is in) there it will find another package called functions, then `from there import set_camera`. But as the error message says:

attempted relative import with no known parent package

python can't find the *parent package* to do the relative import. That parent *package* is not (and for technical reasons, like import hooks, can not be) the parent *directory* of the file you are running. For one, python would have to scan the whole filesystem to find possible packages. Instead, python scans the directory it's run from, in this case `calibration` finds no parent package (or indeed any package structure) and boom. So yes there is another way - give python the fully qualified name of the module you want to run. To do so you need to first rename the shoot-a-photo.py file to be a valid module name shoot_a_photo.py. Then cd to the parent directory of `misc` and use the `-m` switch:

```
$ cd ../..
$ ls
cascade.xml images LICENSE misc ...
$ python -m misc.calibration.shoot_a_photo # note no py
```

This tells python to run the *module* (not *file*) shoot_a_photo who is part of package `misc.calibration`. Package `misc` will be detected alright as a direct child of the working dir, containing an `__init__.py` file, and its subpackages will be indexed.

The -m switch is the canonical way of running a python script that is part of a package